# How to use Rest Debugger for Rest Datasnap in XE7

Tags: delphi, rest, datasnap, delphi-xe7

I'm testing the DataSnap Rest Application in XE7.
I also checked the sample methods 'EchoString' and 'ReverseString'.
I've run the services and I can execute the methodes in the test browser.

But how can I test the methodes in the Rest Debugger.

Methode: Get
URL: http://localhost:8082/reversestring  --> don't know if this is the right thing to do
and where must I set the value like 'ABC' to get 'CBA' after send request.

After using the java console in Google chrome I've catch the url.

The setting in REST Debugger:

```
Methode: GET
URL:http://localhost:8082/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString/ABC
```

Respones in the BODY tab:

```
{
  "result":
  [
    "CBA"
  ]
}
```

It is also possible to set the value in the parameters section.
But It doesn't work. I think I do something wrong.

```
Tab Request  
  Methode: GET
  URL: http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest

Tab Parameters
  Resource: /TServerMethods1/ReverseString
  Request Parameters: [GET/POST] Value=ABC
```

Response > Body

```
 {
   "result":
   [
      ""
   ]
 }
```

I must get result CBA
What I 'm doing wrong in the parameter settings
In the response the url is when I use the parameter section
http://localhost:8082/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/ReverseString?Value=ABC

Find to use the parameter section:

```
Tab Request  
  Methode: GET
  URL: http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest

Tab Parameters
  Resource: TServerMethods1/reversestring/{Value}
  Request Parameters: [URL-SEGMENT] Value=ABC
```

**But how to do with 2 parameters?**

```
function TServerMethods1.MySum(A, B: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result:= A+B;
end;
```

in the parameter section:

```
Tab Request  
  Methode: GET
  URL: http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest

Tab Parameters
  Resource: TServerMethods1/MySum/{A,B}
  Request Parameters: [URL-SEGMENT] A, B= 12, 23
```

--> give error:   "error":"'12, 23' is not a valid integer value"

```
Tab Request  
  Methode: GET
  URL: http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest

Tab Parameters
  Resource: TServerMethods1/MySum/{A},{B}
  Request Parameters: [URL-SEGMENT] A=12
                      [URL-SEGMENT] B=23
```

--> give error:   "error":"'12, 23' is not a valid integer value"

```
Tab Request  
  Methode: GET
  URL: http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest

Tab Parameters
  Resource: TServerMethods1/MySum/{A}{B}
  Request Parameters: [URL-SEGMENT] A=12
                      [URL-SEGMENT] B=23
```

give result 1223, the param A= 1223 and B =0 in the function.
This is not the right input, I mis something?

**Find the solution for 2 parameters**

```
Tab Request  
  Methode: GET
  URL: http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest

Tab Parameters
  Resource: TServerMethods1/MySum/{A}/{B}
  Request Parameters: [URL-SEGMENT] A=12
                      [URL-SEGMENT] B=23
```

Learn something today. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

See blog post from David I on using REST debugger with DataSnap REST servers:
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2014/01/17/43254#comment-111140

Note: in URL you specify a {value} part which you set in Parameters section.

Comment: I can get a result when I use the parameter section. I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Ravaut123: don't forget the { } characters in the URL.

Comment: http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/reversestring/{ABC}  give me "" as result, http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/reversestring/ABC give me "CBA" as result, But how to use the Parameters session?

Comment: @Ravaut123: ABC returns CBA. That works. For parameters you have to use http://localhost:8081/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/reversestring/{value} and then you define Parameter section like in blog post from David I I mentioned above: "Parameters/Add with kind: URL-Segment, name: value, value: ABC". That should also return CBA but now you are working with parameters.

Comment: And how to do with two parameters?

Comment: I found it for 2 params

Answer (score -2):

try

http://.../datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/MySum/12/23